# how can I implement free html5 responsive template in DNN9.x?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, dotnetnuke

I try to implement any HTML 5 responsive template in DNN9.x it is worked in asp.net MVC5.
my problem is in dnn9 do not see jquery,bootsrtapor images sources? he takes styles from dnn style?
so if any topic,notes,links any thing to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to adjust how you are adding resources. Here's an example of resources that I'm importing in one of my open source skins.

```
<dnn:META ID="mobileScale" runat="server" Name="viewport" Content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<dnn:JQUERY ID="dnnjQuery" runat="server" jQueryHoverIntent="true" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="bootstrapJS" runat="server" FilePath="js/bootstrap.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="10" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="bootStrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="DnnCssInclude1" runat="server" FilePath="css/hhfonts.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
```

For a more detailed example check out https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerHead/blob/master/Home.ascx

Comment: hello Chris, can you make a short  video in on your YouTube channel explain that,actually I followed you on you-tube,your website and in DNN community.and I loved work in DNN9.x and I watched all tutorial in your You Tube channel.